# Facebook Test User vs "real" user

Tags: javascript, php, facebook

I'm developing an App with the Javascript and PHP SDK's. The javascript logs the user in, then passes off to the PHP code for most of the work.

The problem that I'm having is that test users and "real" users work differently. I'm calling FB.login, with scopes beyond the standard:

```
FB.login( function(response) {
  if (response.authResponse) {
      handleLoginStatusChange(response);
  } else {
     console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
  }
}, 
{ 
   scope: 'email,public_profile,manage_pages',
   return_scopes: true
});
```

When this runs for the test user's account, the javascript presents two permissions windows - the first one for "public profile and email address", click "Okay", and I get a second one "manage your Pages". No warnings. And my app proceeds normally.

When I run it on a "real" account, the second window doesn't pop up, so my app doesn't have permissions to manage pages. Any idea why the two accounts would be behaving this way?

Comment: _“Any idea why the two accounts would be behaving this way?”_ – because the real account doesn’t have a role in the app, and therefor can be asked for `manage_pages` permission only after you submit your app for review.

Comment: Yep, thanks, figured that out. I'm taking over this app after someone else left it. I would have thought that the app would have access to pages, since the old version of the code did so, but I was wrong. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As CBroe pointed out, the App hadn't been properly reviewed. Thanks.